# Linux bridge blocks UDP packet from tap interfaces

Tags: linux, firefox, ipv6, udp

**Introduction:** I'm working on a 6lowPAN projects of Wireless Sensor Networks. Basically, I have a set of nodes (Contiki OS) which are running on a linux host. Each nodes have its own tap interface which are bridged on br0. Inside the bridge, all things are working well : node can send request and receive properly neighbor exchanges. All exchanges are using 6lowPAN (IPV6 adaptation).

**Problem**: Now, I'm interested by sending request from the host to nodes. So, I add route rules for the destination bbbb::/64 to br0. I can ping any node from the host linux, unfortunately UDP requests fail. I'm using Firefox to send (through the Copper plugin) a UDP packet which is correctly received and processed by the node, but the response is rejected by the bridge which replies host unreachable (Port unreachable).

**Questions**: Are there constraints or particular behaviours on routing rules between bridge and its host? How can I get more log information about Linux's IP stack to determine why it doesn't forward packets to the Firefox socket?

**Investigation**:

- I checked with `netstat` if Firefox is effectively listening on the proper response port [OK]
- I checked with `nc` if the host allows UDP IPv6 exchange [OK]
- No firewall rules [OK]
- I manually added an IPV6 address to br0 bbbb::1/64 with and without routing rules but this didn't work (ping no works at all) [OK]
- A lot of other exotic explorations

**Basic configuration**:

```
brctl addbr br0
ip tuntap add dev br0 mode tap
brctl addif br0 tapXXX
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
ip -6 route add bbbb::/64 dev br0
ping6 ff02::1 -I br0 [OK]
ping6 bbbb::ff02:1:2:3 [OK]
firefox on coap://[bbbb::ff02:1:2:3]/hello <= FAILED (response is blocked by br0 bridge)
```

**Logs**:

ifconfig

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e2:81:42:77:bf:10  
          inet6 addr: fe80::28bf:62ff:fed7:54ac/64 Scope:Link
```

`netstat -p6`

```
AIC Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
udp6       0      0 fe80::28bf:62ff:f:46939 bbbb::ff:fe00:1%1:5683  ESTABLISHED 2544/firefox
```

Wireshark

```
fe80::28bf:62ff:fed7:54ac   bbbb::ff:fe00:1       COAP     73     Confirmable, GET, /hello1  
fe80::ff:fe00:1             fe80::28bf:62ff:fed7:54ac COAP     83     Acknowledgment, 2.05  
fe80::28bf:62ff:fed7:54ac   fe80::ff:fe00:1       ICMPv6   131    Destination Unreachable (Port unreachable)
```

Comment: Have I understood correct that you are using Cooja simulator? Personally I had always been a little uncertain what both addresses mean and it seemed that `fe80::` didn't work - I couldn't ping it. ... Though it occurs to me that you might have a firewall issue. You said you've checked, could you, by chance, confuse `iptables` vs `ip6tables`?

Comment: Indeed, I have already checked ip6tables and there is no rule. I don't use cooja, I compile contiki-os on minimal-net (X86 target) to start all contiki nodes like native applications on my linux, then each of them are directly connected on a big common bridge br0. All is working well until I want to use my linux host to exchange with nodes. Transport layer is blocked on bridge (tap-side), the bridge has an unidirectional behaviour for udp packet...